# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{2^{\sin(\pi x)}-2^{\tan(\pi x)}}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

I am stuck at evaluating this limit:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\frac{2^{\sin(\pi x)}-2^{\tan(\pi x)}}{x-1}$$
Can someone help me, please?

Also, I am not supposed to use L'Hospital's rule or derivatives. Thanks!

Comment: @CookieDog So what tools ARE you allowed to use?

Comment: Calculus with limits and remarcable limits only :( with some (logical) tweaks like substitution of x with some t, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this.

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal L &=&\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{2^{\sin \pi x}-2^{\tan \pi x}}{x-1}=\\
&\stackrel{x-1 = t}{=}&\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2^{-\sin \pi t}-2^{\tan \pi t}}{t}=\\
&=&\lim_{t\to 0} \left(\frac{2^{-\sin \pi t}-1}{t}-\frac{2^{\tan \pi t}-1}{t}\right)=\\
&=&\lim_{t\to 0} \left(\frac{e^{-\sin\pi t\log 2}-1}{t}-\frac{e^{\tan\pi t\log 2}-1}{t}\right)=\\
&=&\lim_{t\to 0}\left[\frac{e^{-\sin\pi t\log 2}-1}{-\sin\pi t\log 2}\cdot \left(-\frac{\sin\pi t \log 2}t\right)-\frac{e^{\tan\pi t\log 2}-1}{\tan \pi t \log 2}\cdot \left(\frac{\tan \pi t \log 2}{t}\right)\right]=\\
&=&\lim_{t\to 0}\left(-1\cdot \pi \log 2-1\cdot \pi \log 2\right)=\\
&=&-2\pi \log 2,
\end{eqnarray}
where we simply used fundamental limits, i.e.
$$\frac{e^{\alpha(x)}-1}{\alpha(x)} \to 1,$$
and
$$\frac{\sin\alpha(x)}{\alpha(x)} \to 1$$
when $\alpha(x) \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can then replace $x = y+1$ which gives you 
$$\lim\limits_{y \to 0}\frac{2^{-\sin(\pi y)}-2^{\tan(\pi y)}}{y}$$

Now, convert numerator in the power of e, then expand using
[this formula.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDGBr.png)
You can then easily evaluate.

Comment: But series are not allowed according to OP